# disable old version of php-fpm after upgrade from 7.0 to 7.1

Tags: php

I upgraded from php-fpm 7.0 to 7.1 but the 7.0 is still running. How do I disable it?

This is the output from top;

```
 1251 ubuntu    20   0  464760  48424  40448 S  0.0  4.8   0:00.03 php                                                                                                            
 1002 root      20   0  506216  47480  39856 S  0.0  4.7   0:00.03 php-fpm7.1                                                                                                     
 1048 root      20   0  311664  29788  24032 S  0.3  2.9   0:00.03 php-fpm7.0                                                                                                     
 1176 www-data  20   0  506216   9396   1772 S  0.0  0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1                                                                                                     
 1177 www-data  20   0  506216   9396   1772 S  0.0  0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1                                                                                                     
 1173 www-data  20   0  311664   7252   1496 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.00 php-fpm7.0                                                                                                     
 1174 www-data  20   0  311664   7252   1496 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.00 php-fpm7.0
```

Comment: `service php-fpm7.0 stop` or `systemctl stop php-fpm7.0`

Comment: Failed to stop php-fpm7.0.service: Unit php-fpm7.0.service not loaded.

Comment: Both command return
Failed to stop php-fpm7.0.service: Unit php-fpm7.0.service not loaded.

Answer (score 8):

do this;

```
sudo systemctl disable php7.0-fpm.service
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Don't do this. After did this my php system just got down !!!

Answer (score 1):

the name of services can be different, in my case the name is without dot(`.`).  to check the right service name just use

```
systemctl | grep php
```

will return:

```
● php-fpm.service loaded failed failed    The PHP FastCGI Process Manager 
  php72-php-fpm.service  loaded active running   The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
```

in above case, to disable just use:

```
systemctl disable php72-php-fpm.service
```

You dont need to reboot. It's work perfectly without reboot.